# Highlight table view cell programmatically

Tags: uitableview

I have a cell in a static table view which I want selected (highlighted blue) when the view appears. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I have tried using `cell.selected = YES;`. This will make the cell selected for a very short time (it goes blue, then white just after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I used `cell.selected = YES;` in `viewDidLoad`. Doing it in `viewDidAppear` will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write `cell.selected = true` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` also.